# Angularjs - What is the best way to seperate services and controllers into separate files?

Tags: angularjs, controller

Sorry but I am unable to find any documentation on this.

I have one app.js file that has all of my services and controllers.

I would like to separate them into different files, under different directories. 
E.g. file structure

app.js

/controllers/controllerName.js

/services/servicesName.js

There looks to be different approaches.

Is this the best way to create a service in a seperate file?

```
angular.module('Data')
    .factory('Data', function($http) {  code  });
```

How would I include this in my app.js?

And would I need to include all three files in the index.html?

existing app.js is below...

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngSanitize' , 'ngTouch' , 'ngAnimate']);

// Service
App.factory('Data', function($http) {
    var promise;
    var jsondata = {
        get: function() {
            if ( !promise ) {
                var promise =  $http.get('src/app_preprocess/data_json.js').success(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
                return promise;
            }
        }
    };
    return jsondata;
});

App.controller('ControllerOne', function (Data , $scope) {
    Data.get().then(function(d) {
        $scope.paraOne =  d.data.PACKAGE.ITEM[3].TEXT_COMPONENT[0].TEXT[0]
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to include any separate JS file into index.html. This can lead to quite a long list of included scripts if you separate everything into different files (which I recommend). There are two ways to split all your files up. One way is into a controllers file, a services file, etc. The other is to group items by the feature they support. I prefer the 1st way (at least within a module) since there isn't always a clear line between functionality (if there is you may want to create a different module).

As long as your app.js file is included in the HTML before your factory, you don't need to do anything special to get Data "into" the app - that's what you're doing when you run `angular.module('App')` (not `angular.module('Data')`). Just inject `Data` into whatever controller or factory you need it in!

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close since this is really just an opinion matter, but there are two major approaches people tend to take.  That said since I have my own opinion I'm gonna post it here anyway ;)

Either create a folder for controllers/directives/services/views or create a directory structure that reflects the functional elements.  I tend to go the second route since then you can create a new module for each script file and each script file contains functionality that works together.

What I end up with is script files that have something like this going on:

```
angular.module("surveyModule.services", []).service('surveyService', ["$http", "$q" ,function ($http, $q) {
//service code here
}])
angular.module("surveyModule.controllers", []).controller('SurveyGeneratorCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$location',
'$routeParams',
'$dialog',
'surveyService',
function (
  $scope,
  $location,
  $routeParams,
  $dialog,
  surveyService) {
//controller code here
}

angular.module('surveyModule', ['surveyModule.services','surveyModule.controllers']);
```

Then in my mainApp.js I include my modules like:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", [
  'userModule',
  'gardenModule',
  'loginModule']);
```

In my index.html I am including all the script files but since each script file defines a new module and nothing happens until it's all loaded and angular bootstraps it all works out.